# Atom won't search (ctrl-p) files, that aren't in current git repo (grey folders)

Tags: editor, shortcut, atom-editor

Atom won't search (ctrl-p) files, that aren't in current git repo (grey folders). I really need that function, and files that i have to look up (framwework files) are in grey folders, where ctrl-p (file search) doesn't reach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *Fuzzy Finder* ignores files that are ignored by your VCS (Git in your case) by default.

You can change that behavior by removing the check on the "Exclude VCS Ignored Paths" checkbox in the general settings:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can choose Find - Find File from menu of Atom to search files.